# using dispatch in components

Tags: reactjs, redux

A question on the `dispatch()` function, so we normally code like below:

```
const store = () => {
    const store = createStore(
        combineReducers({
            expenses: expensesReducer,
            filters: filtersReducer
        })
    );
    return store;
};
store.dispatch(...); // passing an action object
```

but if we use 'connect' to connect a component, and inside the component, we can code like:

```
props.dispatch(...);
```

I understand the fact that dispatch is passed to the component, but the props is not a store, so how can you do like `props.dispatch(...);`? Isn't that dispatch() method can only be used on 'store' object?

Comment: What you are looking for is to pass an action to the component. actions then receive dispatch that will be called. https://redux.js.org/basics/actions. I built a little redux boilerplate, if you want to check it out https://github.com/Mbeaulne/react-redux-boiler/tree/master/src (however its a little rough around the edges, so don't simply copy and paste)

Comment: `dispatch` is injected into the props of the component via `connect`, so once you have call the `connect()` function on a component, it'll have access to `dispatch` on the store via props

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of what a project can look like

component.js

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';



import { login } from './actions';


const Component = ({name, loginAction}) => {

    return <div onClick={loginAction}>login</div>;

}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  name: state.user.name
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  loginAction: login
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Component);
```

action.js

```
export const loggedIn = payload => ({ type: "LOGIN_USER", payload });

export const login = () => dispatch =>  dispatch(loggedIn(true));
```

Actions will receive dispatch when `mapDispatchToProps`. You don't have to do anything special. simply include your action and redux the library will do everything else for you.

EDIT: You don't need dispatch at all. this should work to update the store.

action.js

```
export const login = payload => ({ type: "LOGIN_USER", payload });
```

Comment: isn't that dispatch() method can only be used on 'store' object?

Comment: Sorry, there is a little 'mistake' in my code. `login` is actually used when you have an API call. I'll update my code.

Comment: Dispatch gets used when connecting redux to a component. My ```mapDispatchToProps ``` is using dispatch behind the scenes (this is the shorthand so you do not have to write a lot of boilerplate, and is recommended in various tutorials by the creators of redux). You don't have to worry about "dispatch" explicitly unless your action does an API call or calculations or something

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `connect` from redux to bind your component to store , there the `dispatch` method is getting connected to the store

> Your mapDispatchToProps functions are expected to return an object. Each fields of the object should be a function, calling which is expected to dispatch an action to the store.

[Redux documentation about matchDispatchToProps](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#returns-1)

I hope that answer your question how you are getting dispatch method od store in your component.